# How to load data to gridview programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

This is my  table

```
A/C Type  A/c No  Mode    Amount  Balance
----------------------------------------                 C -> Credit
  A        101    C       500     1000                   D -> Debit
  B        102    D       1000    200
```

I want to show it in a gridview as follows....

```
A/C Type  A/c No  Credit   Debit     Balance
----------------------------------------
  A        101     500      -         1000
  B        102      -       1000      200
```

This is my code and am using C# ASP.NET and  SQL SERVER...

```
connstr = c.Get_ConnString(StrSubbrcode[I], ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ToString()); //Connection string
                if (connstr != "")
                {
                    c.dr = c.ProcExeReader("SELECT....", connstr);
                    if (c.dr.Read())
                    {
                        K = K + 1;

                        c.Connect(connstr);

                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT..", c.con);
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        c.con.Close();
                    }
                }

if (K > 0)
            {


                gv_deposit.DataSource = ds;
                gv_deposit.DataBind();
            }
```

Regards,

Comment: How many records per account will exist in the table? one or two or more?

Comment: @JQone...many records are there

Comment: do you use sql for selecting data? datasets in .net? what are the technologies you use?

Comment: This is a really vague question right now. To answer it, we need a lot more detail about the technologies you're using than you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using case in sql like

```
select 
case when mode ='C' then amount else '-' end as credit,
case when mode ='D' then amount else '-' end as debit
from tbl
```

Comment: @V4Vendetta...let me check it